# WebClient.OpenRead exception: "Value cannot be null."

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, webclient

I'm developing a scraper that scrapes one web page for links, then creates threads which execute 
scraping of subpages.

This is what a thread does:

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
Dim stream As Stream = client.OpenRead(_Address)
Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(stream, True)
_Content = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
streamReader.Close()
streamReader.Dispose()
stream.Close()
stream.Dispose()
client.Dispose()
```

I've noticed that sometimes (usually when there are more simultaneous threads running) a thread throws an exception. It happens randomly, the exception is thrown at `client.OpenRead` and it says `"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: address"`. I also have a try..catch here so I put a breakpoint in the catch block and it appears that the `_Address` is valid at the time, yet the code throws an exception.

`_Address` is a protected class field and cannot be accessed by other threads.

The exact message is:

> "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: address".

The exception is `System.ArgumentNullException`.

Stack trace is:

> at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(String address) at MyAppName.Scraper.Scrape() in MyAppFolder\Scraper.vb:line 96

Do you have any suggestion on fixing the issue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using this code in a static (Module/Shared) class/method?

Comment: Posting the error message and stacktrace would be a good idea. And since it's about _Address, where does it come form?

Comment: @Oded No, the code inside a method of a public class.

Comment: @Henk Holterman The exact message is "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: address". The exception is System.ArgumentNullException. Stack trace is: "at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(String address)    at MyAppName.Scraper.Scrape() in MyAppFolder\Scraper.vb:line 96"

Comment: @Witchunter - please _edit_ your question and add the stack trace and other information _in the question_. Being in comments it may be glossed over and is definitly harder to read.

Comment: @Oded Sorry, I'm not much experienced at StackOverflow. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Where is "_Address" defined? Does anything edit it? It sounds like it might not be thread safe...

Comment: @Witchunter - no problem... we are all learners here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal implementation for `WebClient.OpenRead(string address)` is just:

```
public Stream OpenRead(string address)
{
    if (address == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("address");
    }
    return this.OpenRead(this.GetUri(address));
}
```

so `_Address` must be null when it gets passed in.

Maybe try something like this:

```
private string _address;
private string _Address
{
    get
    {
        if(_address == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("_Address was never set and is still null!");
        return _address;
    }
    set
    {
        if(value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("_Address can not be null!");
        _address = value;
    }
}
```

So basically if something tries to set _Address to null, you will get an error right when it happens and can see in the call stack where it is being set to null.

Comment: I up voted you because that is what I would do: check for null values and either immediately throw an exception or rely on a default value if logic dictates to do so.  Just for future curtsey, please convert to VB.NET prior to posting (converter whatever) since this was tagged as 'VB.NET'. Thanks.